# Manual resizing of chrome viewport has different results from resizing in browser using "Inspect"

Tags: html, css, wordpress, google-chrome, responsive

I'm trying to create a responsive custom theme for Wordpress. I'm hosting it locally with WAMP and using a variety of tools to make sure it's mobile friendly. Problem is, I'm not getting consistent results and I can't test on an actual mobile phone until the theme has been uploaded to the actual site (kind of defeats the purpose of hosting and coding locally!).

Results from using the Chrome "Inspect" function:

[image]

So far so good, even when the viewport width is less than 320px. Right?

Results from manually resizing the Chrome browser window:

[image]

Just kidding, the design breaks at 363px.

So which is going to show up on mobile devices? Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're likely going to see that the manual resizing of chrome is more accurate to what you would see on a mobile device, but the best way to find out is to test it on a mobile device.

You can test the site WITHOUT deploying it to a server fairly easily as long as you're running a local server (`localhost`, or `127.0.0.1`). Here's how:

1. Make sure your mobile device and the computer running the local server are connected to the same wifi network.
2. Find out your local network IP address. Here's a handy link: http://lifehacker.com/5833108/how-to-find-your-local-and-external-ip-address
3. Type your local network IP address into your mobile device's browser, followed by the port you are running the local server on.

   > Example:  If your local network IP address is `192.168.1.11`, and you have been accessing the site at `localhost:5000`, you can access the site on your mobile device at `192.168.1.11:5000`.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using white-space:nowrap to make sure it looked fine both ways. Unfortunately, I still can't access my site via mobile. Following your instructions (and of other online tutorials), I get a 403 forbidden page. I'm guessing I have to do something with firewalls, but it's a private/home network so I didn't think there would be a problem there... If it helps, I'm using WAMP Server and I access the site at localhost:8080/wordpress